# C# Loop through List of names and display names on a different label each time it loops

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, random, label

I am creating this Random Draw application. For example, User enters in 6 names, they then hit the randomize button and it displays the names randomly in labels beside each other. So for example name at index[0] will play name at index[3] and so on. The problem I am having is I'm not sure how to loop through and display each name on a different label. Is there a way to count my labels and loop through that way? Here is my code for looping through the names in the List and randomly picking one to display on the first label.

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int index = rand.Next(names.Count);
            var name = names[index];

            lblFirstName.Text = name;
            lblFirstName.Visible = true;
            names.RemoveAt(index);
        }
```

As you can see the name will always be displayed on lblFirstName. I have 5 more labels named lblSecondName etc..

Comment: `Random rand = new Random();` always outside the loop otherwise you could get duplicate results

Comment: @fubo Thanks for the tip, I'll change that

Comment: `new Random();` is equal to `new Random(seed : CurrentMilliSecond);` and thus you have a *same* value for (allmost) all the items since `CurrentMilliSecond` *doesn't change* within the loop

Comment: Why not simply add your labels to a list before your loop? Then you could access each like `labels[i].Text = ...`

Comment: @blins yes I see what you mean, but then I would have to programmatically set the position of each label so they do not display over one another? is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a While instead of a For
2. Put your labels on the same control (ex. Panel1)

   ```
   List<string> labels = new List<string>() { "lblFirstName", "lblSecondName" , "lblThirdName" , .......... };
   while (names.Count > 0) {
       Random rand = new Random();
       int index = rand.Next(names.Count);
       var name = names[index];
       names.RemoveAt(index);

       index = rand.Next(labels.Count);
       //WebForms
       Panel1.FindControl(labels[index]).Text = name;
       Panel1.FindControl(labels[index]).Visible = true;

       //WinForms
       Panel1.Controls(labels[index]).Text = name;
       Panel1.Controls(labels[index]).Visible = true;

       labels.RemoveAt(index);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. solved my issue although it needed a few tweaks, it helped me solve so thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstNames = new [] { lblFirstName1, lblFirstName2 , lblFirstName3 , .......... };

for(int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int index = rand.Next(names.Count);
            var name = names[index];

            firstNames[i].Text = name;
            firstNames[i].Visible = true;
            names.RemoveAt(index);
        }
```